# Adding string literals support in parser

Tags: haskell, megaparsec

Now I'w working on my university homework and one of the tasks is to add string literals support in my Haskell parser of dummy programming language (named "Hi").

I solved this task with that code:

```
parseString = do
   res <- char '\"' *> manyTill charLiteral (char '\"')
   return (HiValueString (pack res))
```

But I don't understand how to solve this task using `between`?
I want to make code of this parser shorter, like:

```
parseString = do
   res <- between '\"' '\"'
   return (HiValueString (pack res))
```

Comment: I don't think you need to escape double-quotes inside single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`between` takes parsers, not characters, as arguments. You need two (trivial) parsers that each parse `'"'`, as well as the parser for what you want between the quotes.

```
parseString = do
    let quoted = between (char '"') (char '"')
    res <- quoted (many charLiteral)
    return (HiValueString (pack res))
```

Not really any shorter (even ignoring the extra variable binding I introduce for readability), but it lets you separate more cleanly the quoting from the thing being quoted.

Regardless, you can use `<$>` to replace your `>>=` followed immediately by `return`.

```
parseString = (HiValueString . pack) <$> (char '"' *> manyTill charLiteral (char '"'))
```

or

```
parseString = (HiValueString . pack) <$> (between (char '"') (char '"') (many charLiteral))
```